# extracting a dictionary key and assigning it to a variable in python

Tags: python

The file names.dat looks exactly like this:

```
Fry, Philip J.;999 111-1111;999 222-2222  
Rodriguez, Bender B.;999 333-3333;999 444-4444  
Farnsworth, Professor;999 555-5555;999 666-6666  
Leela, Turanga;999 777-7777;999 888-8888  
Wong, Amy;999 999-9999;999 101-1010
```

And the below code gives the printed results down at the bottom. What I want to do is make a menu driven program that will allow the user to choose by number which record they want to modify. In pseudo code it would look something like this:

- The first block of code with the numbered phone listing goes here
- Enter by number the record you want to modify
- User enters 3
- For Rodriguez, Bender B enter a c to modify the cell phone or enter an h to modify the home phone
- User enters h
- Type in the 10 digit phone number with no spaces
- User enters 7771234567
- Record gets changed
- Enter p to view the modified phone book (which would show all the records but with a different phone for Bender
- Would you like to make another modification? y for yes, n for no

My problem is that I can't find a way to bind the primary key to the entered user number. Being that python dictionaries have no order I'm finding this hard to do. Can someone please help? I only need that, the rest I can do myself.

```
pBook = {}  
fp = open('names.dat')  

# populate pBook  
while 1:  
    line = fp.readline()  
    if not line:  
        break  
x = line[:-1]  
data = x.split(';')  
pBook[data[0]] = {'home': data[1], 'cell': data[2]}  
fp.close()  

# optional if you want to see the dictionary structure   
# print pBook  

i = 1  
print '\nPhone listings:\n'  
for record in pBook:  
    key = str(i)  
    i += 1  
    print key + ')', record + ':', 'Home', pBook[record]['home'] + ',', 'Cell', pBook[record]['cell']  
print ''
```

> Phone listings:
>
> 1. Farnsworth, Professor: Home 999 555-5555, Cell 999 666-6666
> 2. Fry, Philip J.: Home 999 111-1111, Cell 999 222-2222
> 3. Rodriguez, Bender B.: Home 999 333-3333, Cell 999 444-4444
> 4. Wong, Amy: Home 999 999-9999, Cell 999 101-1010
> 5. Leela, Turanga: Home 999 777-7777, Cell 999 888-8888

Results of printing pBook after it has been populated, formatted for this post so it's easier understand its structure. The primary key is the person's name, the values is another dictionary where 'cell' and 'home' are keys and the phone numbers are the respective values.

```
{  
'Farnsworth, Professor': {'cell': '999 666-6666', 'home': '999 555-5555'},  
'Fry, Philip J.': {'cell ': '999 222-2222', 'home': '999 111-1111'},  
'Rodriguez, Bender B.': {'cell': '999 444-4444', 'home': '999 333-3333'},  
'Wong, Amy' : {'cell': '999 101-1010', 'home': '999 999-9999'},  
'Leela, Turanga': {'cell': '999 888-8888', 'home': '999 777-7777'}  
}
```

Comment: I assume you have an indentation error in the `while` loop under `#populate pBook`, otherwise you're not going to populate it with very much.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure. Use a `list`, not a `dict`, and your troubles will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think the whole design is wrong, because once you are going to have a huge phone book, I don't see any point in printing it and to let the user choose.

But, in case that you want to bind the name and the user choice (number) you can create a dictionary while printing it to the user:

```
user_choices = {}
i = 1  
print '\nPhone listings:\n'  
for record in pBook:  
    key = i
    user_choices[key] = record 
    i += 1  
    print str(key) + ')', record + ':', 'Home', pBook[record]['home'] + ',', 'Cell', pBook[record]['cell']  
print ''
```

Then to get the cell number of Wong, Amy you can `print pBook[user_choices[4]]['cell']`

Comment: You should probably use `enumerate(pBook)` instead of incrementing the variable `i` yourself.

Comment: @zenpoy, that was very helpful. As an FYI to access Wong the code is:  

> print pBook[user_choice[str(4)]]['cell']  

because a string is passed to key, I'll also be trying out the other suggestions.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz I fixed the code - key is now `int` instead of a `string`

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an ordered dictionary use `collections.OrderedDict`

In Python2.7 you can access either the key or value by index using `my_dict.keys()[index]` or `my_dict.values()[index]`.

As pointed out by @mgilson this won't work in 3.0 as it returns a ValuesView object which doesn't supporting indexing, but you can still coerce it to a list like so:

`list(my_dict.keys())[index]`.

Comment: Accessing the keys/values directly like this probably won't work on python 3.x because those methods return view objects which don't support indexing.

Comment: Ah, hadn't realised that, I'm using 2.7 so it works ok.  Thanks for the pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Newer (python 2.7+) versions of python have an ordered dictionary type in `collections.OrderedDict`, however (as far as I can tell), you still can't access that dictionary by index.  I would suggest keeping an ordered data-type along side your dictionary (like a list).  Then, when you want to get a value by an index, you just do `mydict[mylist[i]]`.  You could probably make this a little prettier by subclassing dict, but essentially that's the idea.

Really, if you want to get at the data by an index, you're probably better off using a `list` as your data structure anyway ... This has the advantage that you can sort it (alphabetically for example) and it keeps it's order.

Comment: Yes, doing it with a list is very easy. I had no problems solving it that way. I was interested in seeing if it could be done using a dictionary. I have other programming experience but I'm new to python and I have yet to see a real world situation where it makes more sense to use a dictionary. Maybe I'm wrong about that but because they have no inherent order it makes it very hard to work with them, especially if the primary keys don't resemble integers. And I suppose in part that is what this is about... showing how hard it is to work with them.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz -- Consider the case where you want to access your phone directory by **name** of the person rather than what **position** the person is in the phone book.  In that case, a dictionary is very useful.  Frequently you don't care about the order of your objects, you just care that you have an easy handle on the object you want.

Comment: I can see that especially since in this case the primary key is a person's name, but in this case I see it being easier for the user to access a record by number rather than have them type in a name.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz -- Yep, if you want to have sequential records, a list is what you want.  If you want random access based on something that isn't an integer, dictionaries are good for that.  Consider classes with simple attributes.  `a.foo=3` could be easily done with a dict `a['foo']=3`.  In fact this is exactly what python does (in a somewhat optimized fashion).